# Invoking trigger when an answer is marked as Best Answer in Chatter

Tags: trigger, chatter, feeditem, feedcomment

I am trying to invoke a trigger when an answer is marked as 'Best Answer' in Chatter Question. I tried a trigger on `FeedItem` and `FeedComment` objects, but the triggers were not invoked when I mark an answer as a 'Best Answer'. I am working on Chatter Questions and even tried creating a trigger on **Question** object, but get an error `Invalid type: Schema.Question` while trying to save. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Since a trigger was not able to handle this, I ended up implementing this with ScheduledBatch. If someone has a simpler way to do this, feel free to comment your suggestion.